# From line in cartesian coordinates to polar coordinates with youth style

Tags: 2d, coordinate-transformation

I have line like in 2D defined by ax+by+c = 0  so (a,b,c).
I need to compute a polar representation of this line like Hough approach with rho an theta.

How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

A line in cartesian coordinates is not as easily represented in polar coordinates.

You can simply substitute `x,y` with their respective polar equivalents, `r*cos(theta), r*sin(theta)`, giving you

```
a*r*cos(theta) + b*r*sin(theta) + c = 0
```

This implicit equation is not as easy to figure out, however. But, if you first convert your implicit line equation to a parametric vector equation of the form `(x,y) = R(t) = R0 + t*V`, where `R0,V` are cartesian vectors which you can derive from `a,b,c`, you can then write

```
(r*cos(theta), r*sin(theta)) = R0 + t*V
```

and solve this system of equations for `r` and `theta` in terms of `t`.

---

However, polar coordinates are not the same as the Hough transform.

In the Hough system, the line is defined by the length `rho` of a perpendicular line that crosses `(0,0)` , which is `theta = atan(b/a)`. Figuring out `rho` seems more difficult at first, but [this tutorial](http://matlabtricks.com/post-39/understanding-the-hough-transform) explains it.